# Python - Raw String Literals

Tags: python, rawstring

I don't understand how raw string literals work. I know that when using `r` it ignores all specials, like when doing `\n` it treats it as \n and not as a new line. but then I tried to do this:

```
x = r'\'
```

and it said `SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal` and not '\'

why? did I understanded it correctly?
and also what is the explanation for this :

```
print r'\\' # gives '\\'
print r'\\\' # gives SyntaxError
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only way to put in a single quote into a string started with a single quote is to escape it. Thus, both raw and regular string literals will allow escaping of quote characters when you have an unescaped backslash followed by a quote character. Because of the requirement that there must be a way to express single (or double) quotes inside string literals that begin with single (or double) quotes, the string literal `'\'` is not legal, whether you use a raw or regular string literal.

To get any arbitrary string with an odd number of literal backslashes, I believe the best way is to use regular string literals. This is because trying to use `r'\\'` will work, but it will give you a string with *two* backslashes instead of one:

```
>>> '\\' # A single literal backslash.
'\\'
>>> len('\\')
1
>>> r'\\' # Two literal backslashes, 2 is even so this is doable with raw.
'\\\\'
>>> len(r'\\')
2
>>> '\\'*3 # Three literal backslashes, only doable with ordinary literals.
'\\\\\\'
>>> len('\\'*3)
3
```

This answer is only meant to complement the other one.

Answer (score 6):

In a raw literal the backslash will escape the quote character that is defining the string.

> String quotes can be escaped with a backslash, but the backslash
>   remains in the string; for example, `r"\""` is a valid string literal
>   consisting of two characters: a backslash and a double quote; `r"\"` is
>   not a valid string literal (even a raw string cannot end in an odd
>   number of backslashes). Specifically, a raw string cannot end in a
>   single backslash (since the backslash would escape the following quote
>   character). Note also that a single backslash followed by a newline is
>   interpreted as those two characters as part of the string, not as a
>   line continuation.

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals)